# Convert object to int in Linq Where clause

Tags: c#, linq, int, where-clause

I'm trying to query a collection where a value of a DataColumn is equal to a number. Problem is, I can't convert an object to an int within a Linq query.

The error fires within the where clause. Any suggestions?

Is there a special syntax I'm not aware of?

```
var datos = _dttMasterViewTransaction.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r["JEID"] == FundsID).Select(r => new EntityJESummary()
{
    Test = r["test"]
}).ToList();
```

Comment: What type is `_dttMasterViewTransaction`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Special syntax? Does casting count?

```
_dttMasterViewTransaction.AsEnumerable().Where(r => (int)r["JEID"] == FundsID)
```

Comment: That's literally the first thing I tried but I got an exception. Now it works. Go figure!

Comment: You probably have to do it in the select statement too.